# How to access a class property that is of type object in PHP?

Tags: php

I know how to access an object's property if the property type is a simple `string`

```
class My_Class {
    public $var = 'Hello';

    // More stuff...
}

$obj = new My_Class();
echo $obj->var
```

But imagine if `My_Class::var` was type `object` which itself had properties. How would I access one of those properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just continue working your way down the chain like so:

`$obj->var->property_name;`

Answer (score 1):

The same way you'd access a regular object but working through the instance of the container class. For example:

`$obj->var->some_method() or $obj->var->some_public_property;`